# Why is jquery-ui droppable with "accept" option as a function is ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using jQueryUI 1.12.1 to try to make some `<input type="file">` elements droppable. This works when no options are specified, but when I try to use the "accept" option, specified as a function, nothing happens:

```
$('input[type="file"]').droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    accept: function (draggable) {
        console.log("hi", draggable);
        return false;
    }
});
```

The droppable file input ALWAYS accepts the file, and the function is NEVER called (and the log message is never seen/no breakpoint in the function is hit).

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong are most welcome.

Comment: In what way does it "work" when you don't use the options? What does dropping on the file input do then?

Comment: Browsers have native support for dropping things on file inputs.

Comment: Wow...I am not sure how I managed not to spot that. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar points out, browsers have native support for dropping things on file inputs, so while the call to `.droppable()` does things like add the CSS classes jQueryUI documents to the file inputs involved, the `accept` attribute does not work.

(Perhaps the browser's support is not compatible with the logic that jQueryUI normally applies to droppables; this likely applies in other regards too).